# Profile page bug

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, profile-page

In the registered user section there's a label: *Seen*.

It is showing incorrect information. When I visited my own profile page I got the information:

***Seen: 18 mins ago.***

According to what criteria is this info shown?

Answer (score 3):

The "seen" dates have a granularity of about 15-30 minutes.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure where it gets the information for that section, but the time error has a 99% of being a result of using caching. Wouldn't consider a bug, and isn't all that important anyways; unless of course you're stalking someone.

**Edit:**
After reading your other question I agree that online/offline could be useful, but the specific time of last seen not so much.